Is there a difference between the two
" This week, this has been happening frequently."
"This week, this has happened frequently."
Is there a difference between the two? Or they essentially mean the same thing?

What is the context?  What is "this"?  What does your research or best guess say about the difference between  "has been happening" and "has happened".

The past few days the wifi kept disconnecting. That is what "this" is.

The present perfect progressive/continuous "has been happening" emphasizes the recurrence, and you could also add a "quite" to emphasize the frequency:

This has happened often lately.
This has been happening quite often lately.

